# No consigo cargar recursos en proyecto Web con JSP, Spring y Tomcat

Tags: jsp, aplicación-web, tomcat, spring-mvc

He creado un Dynamic Web Project en Eclipse al que he agredado Spring 5.1.8.

Llamo a varias páginas .jsp  desde el controlador, en una de ellas le he insertado una imagen y un css que tengo metidos en `WebContent/recursos/imgs/paisaje.jpg`, `WebContent/recursos/estilos/bluestyle.css`

Las vistas jps las tengo en `WEB-INF/views` y declaradas en el `spring_mvc_servlet.xml` dentro del bean

```
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
```

y los recursos como:

```
<mvc:resources location="/recursos/" mapping="/recursos/**"></mvc:resources>
```

y en el jsp los cargo como

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/recursos/estilos/bluestyle.css" >
```

y en el  meto la imagen probando distintas combinaciones de rutas, y también con JSP y JSTL, en ningún caso parece hacer caso ha cargado ni el css ni la imagen

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/recursos/imgs/paisaje.jpg" alt="Paisaje" >
```

con JSP

```
<img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/recursos/imgs/paisaje.jpg" alt="Paisaje" >
```

probando combinaciones

```
<img src="/recursos/imgs/paisaje.jpg" alt="Paisaje" >
<img src="./recursos/imgs/paisaje.jpg" alt="Paisaje" >
<img src="recursos/imgs/paisaje.jpg" alt="Paisaje" >
```

con JSTL

```
<img src="<c:url value='/resources/img/paisaje.jpg' />" >
```

En la salida html he comprobado la ruta para contextPath, JSTL y demás combinaciones, usando el contextPath y con JSTL obtengo 
`/ProyectoSpringJSP/resources/img/paisaje.jpg`
el resto simplemente la ruta declarada en entre las comillas

He probado además a cambiar a distintas versiones de Tomcat, 8.0.27, 8.5.43 y 9.0.22, además de la que viene integrada con Eclipse.

También he probado a recrear el proyecto de cero y distintas localizaciones de los recursos, como meterlos directamente en WebContent. Ninguna combinación parece funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Yo veo que pueden ser estos posibles problemas

1.- En tu spring_mvc_servlet.xml añade la etiqueta de annotation-driven al final:

```
....
<mvc:resources location="/recursos/" mapping="/recursos/**"></mvc:resources
<mvc:annotation-driven />
...
```

2.-Intenta acceder a tus recursos usando etiquetas de JSTL

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="<c:url value="/recursos/estilos/bluestyle.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
...
```

3.-O intenta usando las etiquetas de Spring

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <spring:url value="/recursos/estilos/bluestyle.css" />
</head>
<body>
...
```